# Modifying SQL Server database table from Server Explorer in Visual Studio.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am using a SQL Server database from Server Explorer in Visual Studio.NET for an ASP.NET application, and I need to change some table fields' data type from `int` to `uniqueidentifier`. I get the following error message:

> Conversion from 'int' to 'uniqueidentifier' is not supported on the connected database server.

Can I get some help how can I do this modification, thanks?

Comment: Simply because on sql server there is no implicit conversion from int to uniqueidentifier exists.

Comment: First change to varchar and then uniqueidentifier, but make your table empty first.

Answer (score 0):

you have to manually run the script below to change it

First delete data from table and then

`ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
ALTER ColumnName varchar(50)`

and then

`ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
ALTER ColumnName uniqueidentifier`

thats it.